# How to print power set in order each pair of subset differs only one element?

Tags: python, powerset

I want to print a power set in an order such that adjacent subsets will differ by only one element.

For example:

```
Input: S= {1,2,3,4}
```

Output would be printed like this:

```
{"",{1},{2}, {3}, {4} ,{4,1}, {4,2} ,{4,3},{3,1}...}
```

or

```
{"", {1}, {1,2}, {2}, {2,3}, ...}
```

Comment: I do not think the order of input set matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the first 2^N [gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), where N = len(S).  Use the bits of the code to select elements for that set.

```
S = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(2**len(S)):
    gray_code = i ^ (i >> 1)
    subset = [S[j] for j in range(len(S)) if gray_code & (1 << j) ]
    print(subset)
```

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[2]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
[3]
[3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 4]
[4]
```